# Firebase - Cloud Functions in CoffeeScript

Tags: firebase, coffeescript, google-cloud-functions

I've read somewhere that you can write your Cloud Functions using CoffeeScript, but I'm not sure how.

I did

```
npm install --save-dev coffeescript
npm install --save-dev coffee-loader
```

in the `functions` directory and the `devDependencies` object does show the libs in `package.json`

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "coffeescript": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
```

but doing

`const backend = require('backend.coffee')`

in `index.js` results in

`Cannot find module 'backend.coffee'`

**Edit:** The above error is solved by using a relative path (`./backend.coffee`), thanks @caffeinated.tech, but now the coffee file is being interpreted as simple JS code and fails.

The contents of `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.1",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "coffeescript": "^2.4.1",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I never tried coffeescript on google-cloud-functions.  Maybe it will work if you use a relative path for require: `require('./backend.coffee')`. But I would suggest compiling your coffeescript to js before uploading to google.

Comment: @caffeinated.tech oh, thanks, that helped! It does find the module now, but it's trying to parse it as JS, so as you said, it seems like I have to transpile the coffee code to JS and I'm not sure how to do that as part of the deployment process

Comment: Could you share your `package.json` and your deployment process? Do you use / prefer any tools like babel / webpack ?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech thanks for the help, yepp, included it in the question. The deployment process is simply running 'firebase deploy --only functions'. I'm not well travelled in JS land, I've heard of babel / webpack before, but I'm not sure what they are for and how / why would I use them.